# How can I check checkbox using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

```
public void AddIssues()
{
    try
    {
        getChromeDriver().findElementByClassName("odd").click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        getChromeDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        getChromeDriver().findElementById("view-issue").click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        getChromeDriver().findElementById("report-missing-doc-link").click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        getChromeDriver().findElement(By.id("1")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: just emulate a `click`, what exception you are getting. Just a advise: Avoid `Thread().sleep` whenever possible.

Comment: where is the issue? The code will be really slow but should do the thing

Comment: This type exception i was getting.                                                      Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 28917
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: I'm missing the point of the question. You are already checking check-boxes in the posted code, so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: When I run the script i found below exception error in Chrome Browser.                     Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 28917
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this part

```
       `getChromeDriver().findElement(By.id("1")).click();`
```

If yes, wait while element get displayed then click.

```
while(true) {
    if(getChromeDriver().findElement(By.id("1")).isDisplayed())
        break;
}
getChromeDriver().findElement(By.id("1")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out these methods from the [getting started with selenium project](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) :

```
/**
 * Check a checkbox, or radio button.
 * @param by The element to check.
 * @return
 */
public AutomationTest check(By by) {
    if (!isChecked(by)) {
        waitForElement(by).click();
        assertTrue(by.toString() + " did not check!", isChecked(by));
    }
    return this;
}
...
/**
 * Checks if the element is checked or not.
 * @param by
 * @return <i>this method is not meant to be used fluently.</i><br><br>
 * Returns <code>true</code> if the element is checked. and <code>false</code> if it's not.
 */
public boolean isChecked(By by) {
    return waitForElement(by).isSelected();
}
```

[see the file here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/src/main/java/com/company/seleniumframework/AutomationTest.java#L255)

You can see that this will make sure it's checked after clicking.

```
- Is the checkbox / radio button checked?
  If No: click()
  If Yes: return
```

Simple logic.